# Rails ¿Por qué mi create.js.erb no renderiza la vista?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Estoy renderizando vistas mediante AJAX en un tab-pannel, y todas me funcionan menos cuando quiero renderizar _show.html.erb al hacer submit en el form del partial _new.html.erb. A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.

controlador

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_topic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:notice] = "Topic successfully created"
      format.js {redirect_to :controller=> "topics", :action=>"show", :topic=> @topic}
    end
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
    @topic.user_id = current_user.id if current_user

    if @topic.save
      flash[:notice] = "Topic successfully created"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {redirect_to :controller=> "topics", :action=>"show", :topic=> @topic}
        format.html
      end
    end
```

## parte del form

```
  <div id="forumActivity">
     <%= form_for @topic, :remote => true do |f| %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :competition_id,  :value => params[:competition_id], class: "idcomp form-control" %>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, rows: 2, placeholder: "Write the title...", class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 10, placeholder: "Write the content...", class: 'form-control' %>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit 'Create Topic', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
      <% end %>
   </div>
```

## create.js.erb

```
$("#forumActivity").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'topics/show' locals: { topic: @topic })  %>");
$('#comments').html("<%=j render @topic.comments %>");
```

## show.js.erb

```
$("#forumActivity").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'topics/show', locals: { topic: @topic } ) %>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da porque la vista `create.js.erb` no se carga debido al `redirect`.

Para que funcione simplemente elimina el `redirect` de `format.js` en la acción `create`:

```
def create
  @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
  @topic.user_id = current_user.id if current_user

  if @topic.save
    flash[:notice] = "Topic successfully created"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

Y también elimina el `redirect` en la acción `show`:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    flash[:notice] = "Topic successfully created"
    format.js
  end
end
```

La vista `show.js.erb` se cargará automáticamente (a través de `render`).

Comment: Hola Gerry, perdona la tardanza pero no he podido contestar antes. He hecho lo que dices y la cosa sigue igual. Actualizo añadiendo `show.js.erb`, por si estuviese haciendo algo mal en ese archivo.

Comment: @JorgeVelaPlaza ¿podrías mostrar el log que se muestra en el servidor y en la consola del navegador?

Comment: ya lo he arreglado, como siempre una tontería. Faltaba una coma en `'topics/show' **,** locals:` de create.js .erb. Eso, y quitando lo del redirect claro. Muchas gracias!!!!